# Implement in operator in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I try to implement this SQL query  in Entity Framework

```
select * 
from students 
where student.fieldid in (select fieldid from fields where groupid = 10)
```

I guess this is an approach:

```
var fields = context.fields.where(t=>t.groupid = 10).toList();

var result = context.students.where(t=> fields.Contains(t.fieldid)).toList();
```

but this is not working!

Has anyone else tried to do something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A SQL `IN` is equivalent to a LINQ `Contains`.

```
var names = new string[] { "Alex", "Colin", "Danny", "Diego" };    
var matches = from person in people
              where names.Contains(person.Firstname)
              select person;
```

So, the SQL statement:

```
select * from students where student.fieldid in ( select fieldid from fields 
where groupid = 10)
```

is Equivalent in LINQ to:

```
var fieldIDs= from  Fids in db.fields
              where Fids.groupid==10
              select Fids.fieldid;

var results= from s in db.students
             where fieldIDs.Contains(s.fieldid)
             select s;
```